# components not rendering dynamically with react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

For some reason the nested routes in my react based application using react-router v4 are not working.

The `Dashboard`  component is rendering 3 child components, namely `Header` , `Footer`  & `Content1` . All of these components render by default on route `/dashboard` but I want the `Content1`  component to change according to the url, i.e. `Content2`  component should render on url `/dashboard/content2` in place of `Content1`  which is not happening and hitting this url throws a 404 error. Any help is highly appreciated. Following is the code:

**index.js**

```
return (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Footer/>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/dashboard/content2" component={Content2} />  // Hitting this route throws a 404 error...
       <Route component={Content1} />
      </Switch>
   </div>
);
```

Comment: How do you think `<Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/content2`} component={Content2} />` will work. So when you open /dashboard/content2, `${this.props.match.path}/content2` wille be `/dashboard/content2/content2` which doesn't match your route and so on, Use `<Route path='/dashboard/content2' component={Content2} />` instead

Comment: Thanks for the correction, edited my question now.

Comment: If it is `/campaigns/content2` how do you expect it to open on `/dashboard/content2`

Comment: typo, yet again!!!

Comment: if you are expecting `/dashboard/content2` to work, maybe you should consider a recursive route like this example: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/recursive-paths